# Testing floating point logic using chai-almost and sinon `calledWithMatch`

Tags: javascript, floating-point, chai, sinon

I have a test case which is failing because a value being tested is off by `Number.EPSILON`. I understand why this is happening and believe I need to alter my test case so that it tolerates this discrepancy. I believe using [chai-almost](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-almost/) to assist in this makes sense, but I'm struggling to figure out how to integrate `chai-almost` with [sinon-chai](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai) and am looking for ideas.

Specifically, I am using the `calledWithMatch` method provided by `sinon-chai`. The `calledWithMatch` method performs a deep equality check between two objects and does not consider reference equality. I would like to relax this method to tolerate `Number.EPSILON` differences.

The code snippet below highlights the problem with a failing test case. The test case fails because `persist` is called with a bounding box which fails our expectations due to `top` being off by `Number.EPSILON`. In this scenario, the test case should pass as there is nothing incorrect with the data.

```js
mocha.setup('bdd');

const updater = {
  updateBoundingBox(boundingBox) {
    const newBoundingBox = { ...boundingBox };
    newBoundingBox.top -= .2;
    newBoundingBox.top += .2;  
    this.persist(newBoundingBox);
  },
  
  persist(boundingBox) {
    console.log('persisting bounding box', boundingBox);
  }
};

describe('example', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const persistSpy = sinon.spy(updater, 'persist');

    const originalBoundingBox = {
      top: 0.01,
      left: 0.01,
      bottom: 0.01,
      right: 0.01,
    };
    updater.updateBoundingBox(originalBoundingBox);
    chai.expect(persistSpy).calledWithMatch(originalBoundingBox);
  });
});

mocha.run();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/6.1.4/mocha.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.2.0/chai.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/7.3.2/sinon.min.js"></script>
<script>
"use strict";
/* eslint-disable no-invalid-this */

(function (sinonChai) {
    // Module systems magic dance.

    /* istanbul ignore else */
    if (typeof require === "function" && typeof exports === "object" && typeof module === "object") {
        // NodeJS
        module.exports = sinonChai;
    } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(function () {
            return sinonChai;
        });
    } else {
        // Other environment (usually <script> tag): plug in to global chai instance directly.
        /* global chai: false */
        chai.use(sinonChai);
    }
}(function (chai, utils) {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    function isSpy(putativeSpy) {
        return typeof putativeSpy === "function" &&
               typeof putativeSpy.getCall === "function" &&
               typeof putativeSpy.calledWithExactly === "function";
    }

    function timesInWords(count) {
        switch (count) {
            case 1: {
                return "once";
            }
            case 2: {
                return "twice";
            }
            case 3: {
                return "thrice";
            }
            default: {
                return (count || 0) + " times";
            }
        }
    }

    function isCall(putativeCall) {
        return putativeCall && isSpy(putativeCall.proxy);
    }

    function assertCanWorkWith(assertion) {
        if (!isSpy(assertion._obj) && !isCall(assertion._obj)) {
            throw new TypeError(utils.inspect(assertion._obj) + " is not a spy or a call to a spy!");
        }
    }

    function getMessages(spy, action, nonNegatedSuffix, always, args) {
        var verbPhrase = always ? "always have " : "have ";
        nonNegatedSuffix = nonNegatedSuffix || "";
        if (isSpy(spy.proxy)) {
            spy = spy.proxy;
        }

        function printfArray(array) {
            return spy.printf.apply(spy, array);
        }

        return {
            affirmative: function () {
                return printfArray(["expected %n to " + verbPhrase + action + nonNegatedSuffix].concat(args));
            },
            negative: function () {
                return printfArray(["expected %n to not " + verbPhrase + action].concat(args));
            }
        };
    }

    function sinonProperty(name, action, nonNegatedSuffix) {
        utils.addProperty(chai.Assertion.prototype, name, function () {
            assertCanWorkWith(this);

            var messages = getMessages(this._obj, action, nonNegatedSuffix, false);
            this.assert(this._obj[name], messages.affirmative, messages.negative);
        });
    }

    function sinonPropertyAsBooleanMethod(name, action, nonNegatedSuffix) {
        utils.addMethod(chai.Assertion.prototype, name, function (arg) {
            assertCanWorkWith(this);

            var messages = getMessages(this._obj, action, nonNegatedSuffix, false, [timesInWords(arg)]);
            this.assert(this._obj[name] === arg, messages.affirmative, messages.negative);
        });
    }

    function createSinonMethodHandler(sinonName, action, nonNegatedSuffix) {
        return function () {
            assertCanWorkWith(this);

            var alwaysSinonMethod = "always" + sinonName[0].toUpperCase() + sinonName.substring(1);
            var shouldBeAlways = utils.flag(this, "always") && typeof this._obj[alwaysSinonMethod] === "function";
            var sinonMethodName = shouldBeAlways ? alwaysSinonMethod : sinonName;

            var messages = getMessages(this._obj, action, nonNegatedSuffix, shouldBeAlways, slice.call(arguments));
            this.assert(
                this._obj[sinonMethodName].apply(this._obj, arguments),
                messages.affirmative,
                messages.negative
            );
        };
    }

    function sinonMethodAsProperty(name, action, nonNegatedSuffix) {
        var handler = createSinonMethodHandler(name, action, nonNegatedSuffix);
        utils.addProperty(chai.Assertion.prototype, name, handler);
    }

    function exceptionalSinonMethod(chaiName, sinonName, action, nonNegatedSuffix) {
        var handler = createSinonMethodHandler(sinonName, action, nonNegatedSuffix);
        utils.addMethod(chai.Assertion.prototype, chaiName, handler);
    }

    function sinonMethod(name, action, nonNegatedSuffix) {
        exceptionalSinonMethod(name, name, action, nonNegatedSuffix);
    }

    utils.addProperty(chai.Assertion.prototype, "always", function () {
        utils.flag(this, "always", true);
    });

    sinonProperty("called", "been called", " at least once, but it was never called");
    sinonPropertyAsBooleanMethod("callCount", "been called exactly %1", ", but it was called %c%C");
    sinonProperty("calledOnce", "been called exactly once", ", but it was called %c%C");
    sinonProperty("calledTwice", "been called exactly twice", ", but it was called %c%C");
    sinonProperty("calledThrice", "been called exactly thrice", ", but it was called %c%C");
    sinonMethodAsProperty("calledWithNew", "been called with new");
    sinonMethod("calledBefore", "been called before %1");
    sinonMethod("calledAfter", "been called after %1");
    sinonMethod("calledImmediatelyBefore", "been called immediately before %1");
    sinonMethod("calledImmediatelyAfter", "been called immediately after %1");
    sinonMethod("calledOn", "been called with %1 as this", ", but it was called with %t instead");
    sinonMethod("calledWith", "been called with arguments %*", "%D");
    sinonMethod("calledOnceWith", "been called exactly once with arguments %*", "%D");
    sinonMethod("calledWithExactly", "been called with exact arguments %*", "%D");
    sinonMethod("calledOnceWithExactly", "been called exactly once with exact arguments %*", "%D");
    sinonMethod("calledWithMatch", "been called with arguments matching %*", "%D");
    sinonMethod("returned", "returned %1");
    exceptionalSinonMethod("thrown", "threw", "thrown %1");
}));
</script>

<div id="mocha"></div>
```

I am not really sure where to go from here. If I were working with the two entities directly, rather than using `calledWithMatch`, I would explicitly check the `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` values using `chai-almost`. Something similar to:

```
expect(newBoundingBox.top).to.almost.equal(boundingBox.top)
expect(newBoundingBox.bottom).to.almost.equal(boundingBox.bottom)
expect(newBoundingBox.left).to.almost.equal(boundingBox.left)
expect(newBoundingBox.right).to.almost.equal(boundingBox.right)
```

but I haven't been able to see a way to achieve this when using `calledWithMatch`.

Am I missing something? Is there a simple approach to this?

EDIT: Just updating this as I tinker.

I think it's likely the correct approach is to use a custom matcher, but I don't have working code yet: https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/matchers/#custom-matchers

It looks like the functional equivalent of `calledWithMatch(foo)` is `calledWith(sinon.match(foo))` which makes it more clear how to introduce usage of a custom matcher.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, I figured it out.

The trick is to replace the `sinon-chai` method `calledWithMatch` with its lower-level implementation `calledWith(sinon.match`. This allows one to define a custom matcher. I show the one I went with in the example below.

```js
mocha.setup('bdd');

const updater = {
  updateBoundingBox(boundingBox) {
    const newBoundingBox = { ...boundingBox };
    newBoundingBox.top -= .2;
    newBoundingBox.top += .2;  
    this.persist(newBoundingBox);
  },
  
  persist(boundingBox) {
    console.log('persisting bounding box', boundingBox);
  }
};

describe('example', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const persistSpy = sinon.spy(updater, 'persist');

    const originalBoundingBox = {
      top: 0.01,
      left: 0.01,
      bottom: 0.01,
      right: 0.01,
    };
    updater.updateBoundingBox(originalBoundingBox);
    chai.expect(persistSpy).calledWith(sinon.match((boundingBox) => {
        if (!boundingBox) return false;
        
        const isLeftEqual = Math.abs(originalBoundingBox.left - boundingBox.left) < Number.EPSILON;
        const isRightEqual = Math.abs(originalBoundingBox.right - boundingBox.right) < Number.EPSILON;
        const isTopEqual = Math.abs(originalBoundingBox.top - boundingBox.top) < Number.EPSILON;
        const isBottomEqual = Math.abs(originalBoundingBox.bottom - boundingBox.bottom) < Number.EPSILON;
        
        return isLeftEqual && isRightEqual && isTopEqual && isBottomEqual; 
    }));
  });
});

mocha.run();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/6.1.4/mocha.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.2.0/chai.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/7.3.2/sinon.min.js"></script>
<script>
"use strict";
/* eslint-disable no-invalid-this */

(function (sinonChai) {
    // Module systems magic dance.

    /* istanbul ignore else */
    if (typeof require === "function" && typeof exports === "object" && typeof module === "object") {
        // NodeJS
        module.exports = sinonChai;
    } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(function () {
            return sinonChai;
        });
    } else {
        // Other environment (usually <script> tag): plug in to global chai instance directly.
        /* global chai: false */
        chai.use(sinonChai);
    }
}(function (chai, utils) {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    function isSpy(putativeSpy) {
        return typeof putativeSpy === "function" &&
               typeof putativeSpy.getCall === "function" &&
               typeof putativeSpy.calledWithExactly === "function";
    }

    function timesInWords(count) {
        switch (count) {
            case 1: {
                return "once";
            }
            case 2: {
                return "twice";
            }
            case 3: {
                return "thrice";
            }
            default: {
                return (count || 0) + " times";
            }
        }
    }

    function isCall(putativeCall) {
        return putativeCall && isSpy(putativeCall.proxy);
    }

    function assertCanWorkWith(assertion) {
        if (!isSpy(assertion._obj) && !isCall(assertion._obj)) {
            throw new TypeError(utils.inspect(assertion._obj) + " is not a spy or a call to a spy!");
        }
    }

    function getMessages(spy, action, nonNegatedSuffix, always, args) {
        var verbPhrase = always ? "always have " : "have ";
        nonNegatedSuffix = nonNegatedSuffix || "";
        if (isSpy(spy.proxy)) {
            spy = spy.proxy;
        }

        function printfArray(array) {
            return spy.printf.apply(spy, array);
        }

        return {
            affirmative: function () {
                return printfArray(["expected %n to " + verbPhrase + action + nonNegatedSuffix].concat(args));
            },
            negative: function () {
                return printfArray(["expected %n to not " + verbPhrase + action].concat(args));
            }
        };
    }

    function sinonProperty(name, action, nonNegatedSuffix) {
        utils.addProperty(chai.Assertion.prototype, name, function () {
            assertCanWorkWith(this);

            var messages = getMessages(this._obj, action, nonNegatedSuffix, false);
            this.assert(this._obj[name], messages.affirmative, messages.negative);
        });
    }

    function sinonPropertyAsBooleanMethod(name, action, nonNegatedSuffix) {
        utils.addMethod(chai.Assertion.prototype, name, function (arg) {
            assertCanWorkWith(this);

            var messages = getMessages(this._obj, action, nonNegatedSuffix, false, [timesInWords(arg)]);
            this.assert(this._obj[name] === arg, messages.affirmative, messages.negative);
        });
    }

    function createSinonMethodHandler(sinonName, action, nonNegatedSuffix) {
        return function () {
            assertCanWorkWith(this);

            var alwaysSinonMethod = "always" + sinonName[0].toUpperCase() + sinonName.substring(1);
            var shouldBeAlways = utils.flag(this, "always") && typeof this._obj[alwaysSinonMethod] === "function";
            var sinonMethodName = shouldBeAlways ? alwaysSinonMethod : sinonName;

            var messages = getMessages(this._obj, action, nonNegatedSuffix, shouldBeAlways, slice.call(arguments));
            this.assert(
                this._obj[sinonMethodName].apply(this._obj, arguments),
                messages.affirmative,
                messages.negative
            );
        };
    }

    function sinonMethodAsProperty(name, action, nonNegatedSuffix) {
        var handler = createSinonMethodHandler(name, action, nonNegatedSuffix);
        utils.addProperty(chai.Assertion.prototype, name, handler);
    }

    function exceptionalSinonMethod(chaiName, sinonName, action, nonNegatedSuffix) {
        var handler = createSinonMethodHandler(sinonName, action, nonNegatedSuffix);
        utils.addMethod(chai.Assertion.prototype, chaiName, handler);
    }

    function sinonMethod(name, action, nonNegatedSuffix) {
        exceptionalSinonMethod(name, name, action, nonNegatedSuffix);
    }

    utils.addProperty(chai.Assertion.prototype, "always", function () {
        utils.flag(this, "always", true);
    });

    sinonProperty("called", "been called", " at least once, but it was never called");
    sinonPropertyAsBooleanMethod("callCount", "been called exactly %1", ", but it was called %c%C");
    sinonProperty("calledOnce", "been called exactly once", ", but it was called %c%C");
    sinonProperty("calledTwice", "been called exactly twice", ", but it was called %c%C");
    sinonProperty("calledThrice", "been called exactly thrice", ", but it was called %c%C");
    sinonMethodAsProperty("calledWithNew", "been called with new");
    sinonMethod("calledBefore", "been called before %1");
    sinonMethod("calledAfter", "been called after %1");
    sinonMethod("calledImmediatelyBefore", "been called immediately before %1");
    sinonMethod("calledImmediatelyAfter", "been called immediately after %1");
    sinonMethod("calledOn", "been called with %1 as this", ", but it was called with %t instead");
    sinonMethod("calledWith", "been called with arguments %*", "%D");
    sinonMethod("calledOnceWith", "been called exactly once with arguments %*", "%D");
    sinonMethod("calledWithExactly", "been called with exact arguments %*", "%D");
    sinonMethod("calledOnceWithExactly", "been called exactly once with exact arguments %*", "%D");
    sinonMethod("calledWithMatch", "been called with arguments matching %*", "%D");
    sinonMethod("returned", "returned %1");
    exceptionalSinonMethod("thrown", "threw", "thrown %1");
}));
</script>

<div id="mocha"></div>
```